# socket.broadcast.to().emit() returns undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

creating a server for a chat application and where am stuck is the server has to send a message stating an user has joined things where going fine upto this but when i tried to send it to a particular room where the user has joined i used `socket.broadcast.to(room).emit(message)` to send that message to that particular room but what am getting is undefined

the code

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    //join room
    socket.on('joinRoom', ({username, room}) => {
        const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room)
        //welcome  message
        socket.emit('message',formatMessage(canopy,'Welcome to Canopy'))//messsage to the user alone
       
        //broadcast when an user conneccts
        console.log(user.room)
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message' , formatMessage(canopy, `${user.username} has joined the chat`))
    })
})
```

the output am getting is

**Welcome to Canopy**

**undefined**

I dont know why it is showing undefined i tried console logging user.room and user.username i am getting the respective results but when i use to().emit() am getting undefined.

**client side**

```
const chatForm = document.getElementById('chat-form')
const chatMessages = document.querySelector('.chat-messages')
const socket = io()

//get username from url
const {username  , room} = Qs.parse(location.search,{
    ignoreQueryPrefix : true
})
console.log(username)
//join a room
socket.emit('joinRoom', {username, room})


socket.on('message', message => { 
    console.log(message)
    outputMessaage(message)

    //scroll down
    chatMessages.scrollTop = chatMessages.scrollHeight
})


//message submit
chatForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
//get sg txt
    const msg = e.target.elements.msg.value
//send the chat msg
    socket.emit('chat-message',msg)
    //e.input
    e.target.elements.msg.value = ''
    e.target.elements.msg.focus()

})

//output the message to the dom
function outputMessaage(message) {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('message')
    div.innerHTML = `<p class="meta">${message.user}<span>${message.time}</span></p>
    <p class="text">
        ${message.text}
    </p>`
    document.querySelector('.chat-messages').appendChild(div)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed socket.join in server side

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {
    //join room
    socket.on('joinRoom', ({username, room}) => {
        const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room)

        //Join the room
         socket.join(user.room)

        //welcome  message
        socket.emit('message',formatMessage(canopy,'Welcome to Canopy'))//messsage to the user alone
       
        //broadcast when an user conneccts
        console.log(user.room)
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message' , formatMessage(canopy, `${user.username} has joined the chat`))
    })
})
```

Comment: I think you didnt join the room

Comment: nah after joining i got thst output

Comment: But there is no socket.join in your code! I have attached the answer, please have a look